# how do you get the field type (integer, datetime, choice) from the class Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

as the topic suggest, may i know how do i get the field type (integer, datetime, choice) from a listItem?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem(v=office.15).aspx

i would need to know the field type because i need to anticipate it in order to load the appropriate controls (DateTime, Choice, Radio etc) for each individual item.

for example, if a ListItem is a DateTime, then i will load a DateTimePicker control in the row of my table for user to select. TIA

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: can you provide some code snippets? i can't get it to work

Comment: Post the code that you have tried in the question.

Comment: i have solved the issue already. there is a ListItem.ContentType.Fields.FieldTypeKind property which will return the a FieldType enum

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue already. there is a ListItem.ContentType.Fields.FieldTypeKind property which will return a FieldType enum